# Arquillian tomee

Tags: junit, jboss-arquillian, apache-tomee

While executing a test case with arquillian on tomee-remote I m getting the following exception

```
org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: can't get appInfo
```

There seems to be no other exception related to the deployment .
Using the following maven dependencies 
 arquillian-junit-container 1.1.9
 arquillian-tomee-remote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This got resolved .There was a conflicting openejb-core jar of version 4.7.1 in the classpath .Upon removing that it worked